# android Sqlite text data type won't accept white spaces and special characters?

Tags: android, sqlite

In my sql query table is created but value is not inserted

this is my query,

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS BpFullDirectory
( codeval integer primary key, 
  name text, 
  jobTypeName text, 
  DOB text, 
  cid text, 
  countryCode text, 
  countryId text, 
  countryName text, 
  email text, 
  hobbies text, 
  joinDate text, 
  mobileApp text, 
  mobileNumber text, 
  nickname text, 
  officeExtentionNumber text, 
  officeNumber text, 
  phoneModel text, 
  socialMediaPlatform text, 
  subName text, 
  twitterHandle text, 
  imagestring text, 
  jobcategory text);
```

-- and this is my insert table query

```
INSERT INTO BpFullDirectory   
(codeval,name,jobTypeName,DOB,cid,countryCode,
countryId,countryName,email,hobbies,joinDate,
mobileApp,mobileNumber,nickname,officeExtentionNumber,
officeNumber,phoneModel,socialMediaPlatform,subName,
twitterHandle,imagestring,jobcategory)
VALUES('1', 'A Subramanian', 
'Senior Planner', '0000-00-00', '139', '971',
'2', 'Dubai', 'subu@mail.com', 'Reading, Watching TV, Online Chatting, Playing with my Children?', 'Ages Ago',
'Nothing special', '030 - 635 0039', 'Subs', '206',
'02 2331231', 'Blackberry', 'FB', 'test|test',
'Subu Kooliadan', '0139.jpg', '6');
```

I got the error as,

```
 E/SQLiteLog(19242): (1) near "s": syntax error
```

Comment: These particular SQL statements are all right. Post the problematic one. My guess that there's something like an unescaped `'s` in a string literal.

Comment: i don't know where is an error, but this query is working correctly in phpmysql i checked

Comment: Yes, they are, provided the text is enclosed in 'single quotes'. The query you posted works in SQLite and the record is inserted, and can be correctly read back as 
`1|A Subramanian|Senior Planner|0000-00-00|139|971|2|Dubai|subu@mail.com|Reading, Watching TV, Online Chatting, Playing with my Children?|Ages Ago|Nothing special|030 - 635 0039|Subs|206|02 2331231|Blackberry|FB|test|test|Subu Kooliadan|0139.jpg|6` as expected.

Comment: i have checked the inputs separatly, but no unescaped 's in a string

Answer (score 0):

I took the exact code you wrote and placed it on sqlfiddle -

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/fb892/2

Your error is not related to this code